# How can I compare a string in Racket

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, racket

```
(display " Please enter the code : \n")
(define code (read))
(cond
  ((or(string=? code "k")(string=? code "K"))(display "Kid"))
  ((or(string=? code "s")(string=? code "S"))(display "Senior"))
  ( else (display "Adult")))
```

when running it shows up : string=?: expects type  as 1st argument, given: k; other arguments were: "k"

Answer (score 1):

`read` is the default reader. It parses the input as if it is **code**. This if you enter `"hello"` you get a string, but if you enter `hello` you get a symbol. If you enter `(1 2 3)` you get a list with 3 numbers. `read` is what Scheme uses to read your source code.

If you want to read a line of input as string you need to use `read-line` which takes a line of code and returns it as string no matter what the content is.

Instead of comparing to both upper and lower case you can use `string-ci=?`. eg.

```
(string-ci=? "TEST" "test") ; ==> #t
```